# Diffusion Model Failing to Learn

Tags: pytorch, embeddings, diffusion-models

I'm trying to train a diffusion model to map between paired embedding spaces - ie using a CLIP text embedding to predict a CLIP image embedding. I have a working baseline model that predicts the target embedding directly using a MLP. The MLP model works well enough to validate the task is learnable. I'm trying to see if I can improve performance using a diffusion model, similar to the diffusion prior in DALLE2. Unfortunately the diffusion model doesn't seem to learn, and I cant figure out why. Any help or comments are appreciated.

#### Problem setup:

- given paired embeddings `(x,y)`
- sample timestep `t`, random noise `noise`, use noise scheduler to create `noisy_y = noise_scheduler.add_noise(y, noise, t)`
- train model to predict added noise via `noise_prediction = model(x, noisy_y, t)`

#### Model setup:

Noise is added using a DDPM scheduler. Timestep information is converted to an embedding. The model concatenates `[x, noisy_y, timestep_embedding]` and sends that to a MLP to predict the added noise.

```
class DiffusionMLP(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, 
                 n_timesteps, # number of diffusion timesteps
                 d_embedding, # dimension of timestep embedding
                 d_in,        # input embedding dimension
                 d_hidden     # hidden layer dimension
                ):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.noise_scheduler = DDPMScheduler(num_train_timesteps=n_timesteps,
                                             beta_schedule="squaredcos_cap_v2",
                                             clip_sample=False)
        
        self.time_embedding = nn.Embedding(n_timesteps, d_embedding)
        
        self.layers = nn.Sequential(
                                    nn.Linear(d_in*2+d_embedding, d_hidden),
                                    nn.ReLU(),
                                    nn.Linear(d_hidden, d_hidden),
                                    nn.ReLU(),
                                    nn.Linear(d_hidden, d_hidden),
                                    nn.ReLU(),
                                    nn.Linear(d_hidden, d_hidden),
                                    nn.ReLU(),
                                    nn.Linear(d_hidden, d_hidden),
                                    nn.ReLU(),
                                    nn.Linear(d_hidden, d_in),
                                    )
        
    def forward(self, x, noisy_y, timesteps):
        # convert timestep integer to embedding
        timesteps = self.time_embedding(timesteps)
        
        # concat inputs
        x = torch.cat([x, noisy_y, timesteps], -1)
        
        # predict noise
        noise_prediction = self.layers(x)
        return noise_prediction
    
    def predict(self, x):
        
        # create starting noise
        noisy_y = torch.randn(x.shape, device=x.device)
        
        # iterate over diffusion steps
        for t in self.noise_scheduler.timesteps:
            # generate timestep longtensor 
            timesteps = torch.zeros(x.shape[0], device=x.device).long() + t
            
            # predict noise
            with torch.no_grad():
                noise_prediction = self.forward(x, noisy_y, timesteps)
                
            # denoise to previous sample
            noisy_y = self.noise_scheduler.step(noise_prediction, t, noisy_y).prev_sample
            
        return noisy_y
```

#### Training

```
# adam optimizer
opt = optim.AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=1e-4)

# cosine LF schedule
scheduler = get_cosine_schedule_with_warmup(
    optimizer=opt,
    num_warmup_steps=1000,
    num_training_steps=(len(train_dataloader) * epochs),
)

# train loop

for epoch in range(epochs):
    for batch in tqdm(train_dataloader):
        x,y = batch # both x,y are of shape (n, d)
        
        x = x.to(DEVICE)
        y = y.to(DEVICE)
        
        bs = x.shape[0]

        # sample random noise
        noise = torch.randn(y.shape, device=y.device)

        # sample timesteps
        timesteps = torch.randint(0, mapper.noise_scheduler.config.num_train_timesteps, (bs,), 
                                  device=y.device).long()

        # add noise to y embedding
        noisy_y = model.noise_scheduler.add_noise(y, noise, timesteps)
                
        # predict noise
        noise_pred = model(x, noisy_y, timesteps)
                
        # mse loss between noise prediction and input noise
        loss = F.mse_loss(noise_pred, noise)

        # optimizer step
        opt.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        opt.step()
        scheduler.step()
```

When training, the loss drops quickly but then plateaus indefinitely. This behavior happens across a range of learning rates (1e-6 to 1e-3).

If I add capacity to the model (add more layers), the loss plateaus at a higher/worse value.

For validation, I reconstruct `y` embeddings using `model.predict` and measuring cosine similarity between reconstructed and target embeddings. I've observed that lower training loss (noise prediction MSE) correlates with worse validation performance (reconstruction cosine similarity).

The model shows higher loss for early timesteps (ie small amounts of noise added to target)
[image: loss as a function of diffusion timestep]

I tried training only on early timesteps and the model did not appear to learn.

Any thoughts on what the issue may be?